# Making hyperlinks appear in blue

Tags: hyperref, links

How can I make the hyperlinks appear in blue?  I am forced to use some preamble and this is what I found there:

`\usepackage[driverfallback=dvipdfm,hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}`

Hyperlinks are supposed to appear in blue by default but it does not for my document.

Comment: `\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue}`?

Comment: Package `hyperref` has options for this, `\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=somecolor,citecolor=somecolor]{hyperref}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either use options when calling `\usepackage{hyperref}` or `\hypersetup` later on (Please note, that not all options of `hyperref` can be given multiple times in `\hypersetup` again, but the color options are repeatable!)

```
\documentclass{book}

% Load with some options, i.e. \usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref} or blank
\usepackage{hyperref}


% Change the setup later on, after loading hyperref

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue, linktocpage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\clearpage

See \ref{foo} or \ref{foobar} for more information!

\chapter{Foo} \label{foo}

\chapter{Foobar} \label{foobar}
\end{document}
```

The screen shows the ToC with blue hyperlinks to the chapters.

[image]

If the `linktocpage` option is given as suggested by AlexG, the page numbers in ToC are made hyperlinks to the relevant chapter etc, as can be seen in the following screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but I would always use `colorlinks` in combination with `linktocpage`.

Comment: @AlexG: Yes, thanks, I would not use the ToC entry names as links as well. I've added your suggestion to the post.